# Looping over a dictionary keys and values for matching data

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, dictionary

I have one dictionary, with city names, and I am trying to compare if a value (city) exists in a second dictionary with more information (coordinates) and a different length. In case there's a match, it would add that information to a new dictionary based on the information (cities) provided in the first dictionary.

This is what I have so far:

***Code:***

```
# First dic
d = {'City': ["Algeciras", "Piraeus", "Genoa", "Barcelona"]}
# Second dic
d2 = {'Algeciras (ESP)':(33.095, 11.735), 'Piraeus (GRC)': (30.0780555556, 31.31), 'Genoa (ITA)': (33.1772222222, 28.8961111111) , 'Abu Sultan (EGY)':(32.3275, 30.4061111111), 'Madrid (ESP)': (31.322, 24.21)}

# if conversion doesn't find a match:
conversionDefault = 'Unknown (UNK)'
DefaultX = "24.35"
DefaultY = "25.35"

listCities = d["City"]
finalDict = {"City": {}, 'POINT_X': [], 'POINT_Y': []}

for key in d2:
  formatedKey = key[0:key.find(' (')]
  if formatedKey in listCities:
    #finalDict["City"].append[key]
    finalDict["POINT_X"].append(d2[key][0])
    finalDict["POINT_Y"].append(d2[key][1])
  else:
    finalDict["City"]= conversionDefault
    finalDict["POINT_X"].append(float(DefaultX))
    finalDict["POINT_Y"].append(float(DefaultY))
```

I am getting some errors such as "'Dict' Object Has No Attribute 'Append' in Python" and I am also getting a NEW dictionary with more values than the ones provided in the first dictionary.

This would be the desired output:

```
`Final_DICT = {'City': ["Algeciras (ESP)", "Piraeus (GRC)", "Genoa (ITA)", "Unknown (UNK)"], 'POINT_X': [11.735, 30.0780555556, 33.1772222222, 24.35], 'POINT_Y': [33.095, 31.31, 28.8961111111, 25.35]}`
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback. I don't see anything that's trying to append to a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

`finalDict["City"]` should be a list, not a dictionary. Then you can append to it.

You shouldn't assign to `finalDict["City"]` inside the loop, because that will discard all the previous cities. You should append `conversionDefault` to the list.

```
listCities = d["City"]
finalDict = {"City": [], 'POINT_X': [], 'POINT_Y': []}

for key in d2:
  formatedKey = key[0:key.find(' (')]
  if formatedKey not in listCities:
    finalDict["City"].append[key]
    finalDict["POINT_X"].append(d2[key][0])
    finalDict["POINT_Y"].append(d2[key][1])
  else:
    finalDict["City"].append(conversionDefault)
    finalDict["POINT_X"].append(float(DefaultX))
    finalDict["POINT_Y"].append(float(DefaultY))
```